# Google Maps API V3 retrieving data for with and without traffic

Tags: google-maps

I want to access the duration from one point to another point with traffic and without traffic (see picutre below)

[image]

I want to calculate the delay with and without traffic. I can't find the method in the Gogole Maps API v3 that could provide me that data. Or do I have calculate it with other data somehow?

EDIT:
I know how to calculate the duration. The problem is I want to get the duration with traffic and also the duration without traffic (see the picture I provided above), in order to calculate the possible delay time.

EDIT: 
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like that's not possible with the Google API V3 according to this link
[Google maps traffic prediction API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455793/google-maps-traffic-prediction-api-v3)

Does anyone know how I can get the duration from one point to another? It doesn't have to be by Google though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [traffic layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic) from Google Maps JS API.

You need to add to your map the traffic layer:

```
var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);
```

Here there is a [live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4fztpt2k/1/)

And if you want to calculate the duration, there is [a distance matrix API from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)
and in this question from Stackoverflow, you can see [the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408028/calculate-distance-and-duration-through-in-google-maps)

In [Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) you need to give this field:

```
{
  origin: LatLng | String,
  destination: LatLng | String,
  travelMode: TravelMode,
  transitOptions: TransitOptions,
  unitSystem: UnitSystem,
  durationInTraffic: Boolean, /* this is with traffic or without */
  waypoints[]: DirectionsWaypoint,
  optimizeWaypoints: Boolean,
  provideRouteAlternatives: Boolean,
  avoidHighways: Boolean,
  avoidTolls: Boolean
  region: String
}
```

You can try first with the traffic and save the duration and then you can close the traffic option and save it. So you can see the difference between them.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know how to calculate the duration. The problem is I want to get the duration with traffic and also the duration without traffic (see the picture I provided in my opening post), in order to calculate the possible delay time. Hope I could put my points accross.

Comment: So you need to write in your callback and options once with `durationInTraffic: true,` and then `durationInTraffic: false,`, but i am not so sure if it will give you the without traffic version of yours.

Comment: "Note: The durationInTraffic field is now deprecated. It was previously the recommended way for Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers to specify whether the result should include a duration that takes into account current traffic conditions. You should now use the drivingOptions field instead."

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/)

GET request -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=garching&destinations=hamburg&departure_time=now&key=YOUR_KEY
```

will give you `duration` & `duration_in_traffic` for the route-

```js
{
  "destination_addresses": [
    "Hamburg, Germany"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "85748 Garching, Germany"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "761 km",
            "value": 760831
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "7 hours 1 min",
            "value": 25242
          },
          "duration_in_traffic": {
            "text": "6 hours 42 mins",
            "value": 24145
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

The `departure_time` is listed as an optional parameter in the documentation but it is required if you want to see a `duration_in_traffic` estimate.

Hope this helps.